# @Transactional only works in DAO, not in service (No Hibernate Session bound to thread)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional

I have a service method that calls a DAO method. The service method is annotated as `@Transactional`, the DAO method is not. At runtime the following error occurs:

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

When I make the DAO method `@Transactional` as well, it works fine.

How can I fix this without touching the DAO? (Most methods are in a super-class DAO which I don't have access to.)

I'm using `hibernate-core-3.6.8` and `spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE`

The DAOs are annotated as `@Repository`, the services as `@Service`

My `applicationContext.xml` looks like this (I just provided the important parts - let me know if you need more):

```
<bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="at.spardat.deploysolution.process.context.ApplicationContextProvider"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties" location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties">
        <qualifier value="default"/>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:....hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="lobHandler" ref="defaultLobHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" lazy-init="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

    <bean id="dataFieldMaxValueIncrementer" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:incrementerName="TB_OID_SEQUENCE" p:columnName="OID_VALUE">
        <qualifier value="default"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: can you post your Service class and tell us how / from where you are calling it?

Comment: Two things that have gotten me before: 1) Make sure you're importing the right @Transactional annotation (the one from `org.springframework`) and 2) Make sure you're component scanning is set up to scan the packages that your @Service is in

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

hibernate.current_session_context_class=**thread**

in your hibernate properties file

Thanks